# Necessity of valid bit in page tables

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

From Operating System Concepts -

> Valid-invalid bit attached to each entry in the page table:
>
> “valid” indicates that the associated page is in the process’ logical 
>   address space, and is thus a legal page
>
> “invalid” indicates that the page is not in the process’ logical 
>   address space

But if each process has its own page table, by definition wouldn't that mean that every entry in the page table is a valid one? Only the pages associated with that process are entered in its page table, so why do we need to append a valid/invalid bit to each entry?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the page table is "sparse" -- instead of having a table with two columns *{(virtual) page number, (physical) frame number}* which would be difficult for CPU to search through, the page table is essentially a simple array *page_table[page_number]->frame_number*. This way, CPU knows exactly where to search but we need to indicate if the entry is valid or not because we now also have entries for invalid pages.

Answer (score 0):

I think some pages in the process' logical address space may be marked invalid if they have not been dynamically allocated yet. On page 6 of [these slides](http://navet.ics.hawaii.edu/~casanova/courses/ics332_spring14/slides/ics332_mem2.pdf), there is an example of a logical address space with 8 pages, two of which are marked invalid. The slides state that more malloc() calls would use up the invalid pages in the address space. I've searched for an answer to this question as well and this was the only source I found, so please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: That link is now dead.